source tree : Error: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myname/nameGit': CONNECT tunnel failed, response 404
When I try to connect Sourcetree with my Git - source tree can't clone it and this message appears
"This is not a valid source path/URL"
When I click on details, it says:
Command: git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks ls-remote https://github.com/NamePersonne/namegit
Output:
Error: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/NamePersonne/namegit/': CONNECT tunnel failed, response 404
Command: hg identify extensions.hgext.hgsubversion=! https://github.com/NamePersonne/namegit
Output:
Error: abort: error: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:726)
Command: perl.exe C:\Users\33664\AppData\Local\SourceTree\app-3.4.21\tools\svn.pl info https://github.com/NamePersonne/namegit
Output:
Error: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
"le fichier spécifier est introuvable" means "the file specify can't be found"
My PC is on Windows
I have try on another computer to see if the problem is SourceTree, but it have no problem finding the git for the clone. But this computer can't run Unreal.
With the fist computer I have installed gitkraken, and a similar result came, I have no idea what is the problem.

"CONNECT tunnel failed" means you're using an HTTPS proxy. Do you need the proxy at all? Compare its configuration with the other working computer.

I didn't know I have an HTTPS proxy and I don't know how to deactivate it.

echo %http_proxy%? echo %https_proxy%? git config http.proxy?

I am sorry, I don't understand nor know what you are trying to tell me.
Could you tell me where search? I kind just discover the existence of proxy.
